# How to set validation order in symfony, field validation depends on another field?

Tags: symfony

For example, I have an entity with two fields:

```
    /**
     * @Assert\Range(min=1, max=self::SPEND_MAX)
     */
    public ?int $spendMax = null;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    public string $name;
```

How I can set for **spendMax** field, that first of all I need to validate if field **name** is not null, if it's true, that I can start validation Range of **spendMax**.
If **name** is null, then validation of **spendMax** is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own custom method to do the validation and arrange for it to be called before persisting or updating the entity.

Something along these lines:

```
abstract class ValidatableEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function validate(): void
    {
        $validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
                                ->enableAnnotationMapping()
                                ->getValidator()
        ;
        $violations = $validator->validate($this);
        if (0 !== $violations->count()) {
            throw new ValidationFailedException($this, $violations);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Intended to be called from the prePersist Event from EntityPersistenceEventSubscriber service
     * when this object is to be persisted.
     * The method is intended to be overridden in derived classes and does nothing here.
     * If the validation in the derived class is unsuccessful, the method should throw
     * a ValidationFailedException.
     * Note that since the object has not yet been persisted, its ID field will not be defined in this method.
     */
    public function prePersistValidation(EntityManager $entityManager): void
    {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Intended to be called from the preUpdate Event from EntityPersistenceEventSubscriber service
     * when this object is to be updated.
     * The method is intended to be overridden in derived classes and does nothing here.
     * If the validation in the derived class is unsuccessful, the method should throw
     * a ValidationFailedException.
     */
    public function preUpdateValidation(PreUpdateEventArgs $args): void
    {
        // How to get an entity manager here:
        // $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();
        return;
    }
```

To use it, derive your entity class from this one and override the preUpdateValidation and prePersistValidation methods.